# Icon is not updated when updating installation with Inno Setup

Tags: java, jar, inno-setup, launch4j

I developed a Java application with Java 8.112, then I transformed the JAR into EXE with Launch4j 3.11 (32-bit version) and added a transparent icon (.ico) for the executable. To deliver the software correctly with the JRE so that people don't need to download Java 8.112, I used Inno Setup 6.2.1 and added the necessary files which are then compressed in the Inno Setup installer.

Everything works fine, except that if I decide to install the program in `C:\Program Files` it puts me in a test icon that I used before and not the new one that I use. Even if I redo the whole process from the JAR file, give back the correct icon, and install it on another pc, it still gives me the old icon if I install in `Program Files`.

Otherwise, everything works fine if I put the program elsewhere (`C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\My_Program`). How is this possible? Do I have to clear the Launch4j cache or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows caches the Start menu icons. So if you had that entry in Start menu before, reinstalling the application with new icons sometime won't make Windows reset the cache. It keeps displaying the old icons.

Try to uninstall, restart, and reinstall (not sure if that can help).

For a test, you can try using new icon name.

---

Similar question: [Possible to change the application file's icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32898332/850848)